# Баг в Xamarin.Forms при использовании конвертера значений DateTime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Обнаружил баг в Xamarin.Forms при использовании конвертера значений с полем типа DateTime. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался и подскажет как его обойти.
Суть проблемы.
Объявление конвертера в XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:DateToDayOfWeekStringConverter x:Key="dayConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Использование конвертера:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=AlarmTime, Mode=OneWay, Converter=dayConverter}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="30"/>
```

C#:

```
public DateTime AlarmTime { get; set; }

public class DateToDayOfWeekStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        switch (date.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return "Пн";
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return "Вт";
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                return "Ср";
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                return "Чт";
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return "Пт";
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                return "Сб";
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                return "Вс";
            default:
                return "??";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Приложение тупо вообще игнорирует наличие конвертера и выводит в поле дату и время в стандартном формате. При этом никаких сообщений об ошибках нет.
Версия Xamarin.Forms 3.6.0.344457. В предыдущей версии баг также присутствовал

Comment: А в выводе при дебаге есть ошибки? Может, ваш конвертер бросает исключения? Код вашего конвертера вообще вызывается?

Comment: Конвертер обычно задается как `{StaticResource dayConverter}`, а не как у вас.

Comment: Да, вот тут то я ошибку и не заметил. Спасибо. Почему то все другие конвертеры прописал как {StaticResource dayConverter}, а этот нет. Но исключения не возникало. По-видимому код конвертера просто не вызывался. Спасибо